# Router disrupts others connection in college LAN network

Tags: networking, router

My college provides internet connectivity using LAN cables I m using my router to access wirelessly but my router is interfering my other people connected to the college shared network. Why is it so and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use frequency and choose frequency same both in college router and your router, But what is the need of connecting two home routers wirelessly?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).